# Programmatically rename elements by extracting number values and substituting them with small, consecutive integers

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas `Series` where the labels are currently either `None` or a string containing a letter and a number.

I need to relabel the non-None elements, to keep the same groupings and orderings, but replacing the numbers with the smallest consecutive number for each group, beginning with 1 (see example below). I also need to do simple text substitution to replace the letter (which is always "G" with "Group_").

I think I could write some extremely inefficient and long winded code to do this, but I have a feeling that my solution would be at least 100 lines longer than any decent approach. So I'd like to know a good way to do this.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
mydat = pd.Series([None, 'G130', 'G151', 'G142', 'G151', 'G130', None])
```

Resulting data Series:

> ```
> >>> mydat
> 0    None
> 1    G130
> 2    G151
> 3    G142
> 4    G151
> 5    G130
> 6    None
> dtype: object
> ```

Desired Result:

```
>>> mydat
0    None
1    Group_1
2    Group_3
3    Group_2
4    Group_3
5    Group_1
6    None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = mydat.str[1:].dropna().astype(int)
g = 'Group_{}'.format
f = s.factorize(sort=True)[0] + 1

pd.Series([g(x) for x in f], s.index).combine_first(mydat)

0       None
1    Group_1
2    Group_3
3    Group_2
4    Group_3
5    Group_1
6       None
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

```
('Group_'+mydat.astype('category').cat.codes.add(1).astype(str)).mask(mydat.isnull())
Out[1168]: 
0        NaN
1    Group_1
2    Group_3
3    Group_2
4    Group_3
5    Group_1
6        NaN
dtype: object
```